# Is pigpio wave generator suitable for Position PID?

Tags: python, pigpio

Is pigpio wave generator suitable for PID applications (constantly changing its value , on PID update) It is a position PID for a stepper motor with a pulse train driver , it works , however the motor vibrates a little when working , and does not when I run Nema42.avance(ts), not even if I change its values on a for loop, am I doing something wrong? or is there a better alternative for this problem?

this is my stepper motor class

```
class Nema42(object):
    """docstring for Nema42"""
    def __init__(self, pin_direccion , pin_pulse):
        self.pin_direccion = pin_direccion
        self.pin_pulse     = pin_pulse
        self.pi = pigpio.pi()
        self.pi.set_mode(self.pin_direccion, pigpio.OUTPUT)
        self.pi.set_mode(self.pin_pulse, pigpio.OUTPUT)

    def avance(self , tus ):
        if tus == 0:
            self.stop()
        else:

            if tus < 0: direccion = 1
            else : direccion = 0
            self.pi.write(self.pin_direccion , direccion)
            if tus < 1000 : tus = 1000 #Maximum defined motor speed
            if tus > 2500 : tus = 2500 #minimum defined motor speed
            self.pi.wave_clear()
            self.pi.wave_add_generic([
                pigpio.pulse(0,1<<self.pin_pulse,tus),
                pigpio.pulse(1<<self.pin_pulse,0,tus),])
            wid = self.pi.wave_create()
            self.pi.wave_send_repeat(wid)

    def stop(self):
        print "PARADA"
        self.pi.wave_tx_stop()
```

this is the callback I'm running every encoder interrupt

```
def callback(self,way):


      self.pos += way*0.12566370614359174 #linear movement each encoder pulse
      error = self.pid_posicion.pid.update(self.pos)
      if abs(self.pos - self.pid_posicion.pid.set_point) > 0.15:

         if error > 0 : direccion = -1   #define direction 
         elif error < 0 : direccion = 1

         sp = 2500 - abs(error) #de-aceleration sort of ramp based on pid error 
         if sp <0: sp = 1 #saturation for avoiding rotation to the wrong direction
         sp = sp * direccion
         self.pid_posicion.motor.avance(sp) #Nema42 class

      else: 
         self.pid_posicion.motor.avance(0)
         self.cancel()
```

the encoder is being controlled by the [rotary_encoder](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_rotary_encoder_py) class provided on the examples of pigpio

any better alternative?

I'm open to suggestions

thanks in advance

EDIT :

The stepper motor I'm using is a Nema42 , running 400steps per revolution @150 rpm , the for loop I used as a test is the following code

```
import time
from stepper import Nema42

motor = Nema42(12,7)
for i in range(1500):
    motor.avance(2500-i)
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

When I change the Ts of the wave , I get a little overshoot , this doesnt happen con the avobe for loop , probably because of smooth change , however it does happen on the PID update

Comment: What sort of data rates are you talking about?  In particular how many pulses per second.  Could you clarify the comment about it vibrates but doesn't when you use a for loop.  Are you talking about the same software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you don't use wave_clear in the loop.  Use it once at the start of the script.

I would use http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#wave_send_using_mode with sync to ensure there is no discontinuity in the pulses, then wait until you are sure the previous wave has completed and use wave_delete to remove it.

Comment: Hi Joan thanks for your answer , I've searched on pigpio.pi() funcitions , and I couldn't find the wave_send_using_mode() function , is it on a newer version of pigpio? my current version is 1.26 and I'm using python 2.7

Comment: 26 is fairly old.  The current version is 52 on github or http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/download.html.  It is also bundled with the Raspberry Pi Org image at version 50 (sudo apt-get install pigpio python-pigpio python3-pigpio).

Comment: @LuisBorbolla See http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_wave_PWM_py for an example,

Answer (score 1):

Analizing Joan's answer , I modified my code on Nema42 class above , the stepper motor now works really nice :) the code was modified to this

```
class Nema42(object):
    """docstring for Nema42"""
    def __init__(self, pin_direccion , pin_pulse):
        self.pin_direccion = pin_direccion
        self.pin_pulse     = pin_pulse
        self.pi = pigpio.pi()
        self.pi.wave_clear()
        self.pi.set_mode(self.pin_direccion, pigpio.OUTPUT)
        self.pi.set_mode(self.pin_pulse, pigpio.OUTPUT)
        self.wid_vieja = None #define variable for past wave

    def avance(self , tus ):
        if tus == 0:
            self.stop()
        else:

            if tus < 0: direccion = 0
            else : direccion = 1
            self.pi.write(self.pin_direccion , direccion)
            if abs(tus) < 1500 : tus = 1500
            if abs(tus) > 2500 : tus = 2500
            tus = abs(int(tus))
            self.pi.wave_add_generic([
                pigpio.pulse(0,1<<self.pin_pulse,tus),
                pigpio.pulse(1<<self.pin_pulse,0,tus),])
            wid = self.pi.wave_create()
            if self.wid_vieja is not None: #vieja = old
                self.pi.wave_send_using_mode(wid , pigpio.WAVE_MODE_REPEAT_SYNC)
                while self.pi.wave_tx_at() !=wid:
                    pass
                self.pi.wave_delete(self.wid_vieja)
            else : 
                self.pi.wave_send_repeat(wid)
            self.wid_vieja = wid

    def stop(self):
        print "PARADA"
        self.pi.wave_tx_stop().
```

Please excuse my code written half spanish , and half English